# Drives get lock out after restart windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

I have one of my user's machine Windows 10. The users drive is getting locking out (D and E drives only) after every restart. we have a GP to block USB devices and CD Rom to the OU containing this PC. The thing is only this machine is having trouble and there are several other machines under the same OU.
The Event viewer is showing some error in processing this GP also. I tried by giving the machine USB access also but the issue persists. Now every time I need to remove the drive letters, reattach the PC to domain and the connect the drives in Disk Management.
The machine is having the below event records.

Event ID 1058, 219.

Comment: What type of drives are the D: and E: drives? External, Internal? Make, Type?

Comment: all internal drives in the same hard disk.

Comment: The issue is also present in Windows 7

Comment: You need to provide more information so we can help you like can you export the GP setting and where is it located ? Under computer or user configuration ? Is it on user or computer OU and what's the results of RSOP regarding this GP ?

Comment: I found the root cause. The machine is HP Elite 8200, and it is taking internal harddisk as USB hard disk. We have a GPO to block removable devices in the OU and it is making the drives locked.
I am looking for some solutions to fix this issue, because SATA mode is not suporting in UEFI boot mode. SATA option is only available in Legacy boot, and that one is not supporting by Windows.